# Cin can't take input

Tags: c++, class, cin

This is my first time using classes and I'm writing a simple program that will take a certain roman numeral and print out the numerical equivalent. However, I'm struggling to code my user input, my cin >> romanObject.getRomanNumeral(); isn't working. I get error E0349 saying no operator ">>" matches these operands. However, when I used just a simple char variable declared in my main function instead it worked fine. Why doesn't my variable in my class work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class romanType {

public:

    void setRomanNumeral(string x) {
        romanNumeral = x;
    }
    string getRomanNumeral() {
        return romanNumeral;
    }
private:
    string romanNumeral;

};

void store();

int main()
{
    store();
    return 0;
}   

void store() // Takes user input.
{
    romanType romanObject;
    romanObject.setRomanNumeral("Blank");

    cout << "Enter one of the following roman numerals" << endl;
    cout << "I, V, X, L, C, D, M." << endl;
    cin >> romanObject.getRomanNumeral();

}
```

Comment: `string getRomanNumeral()` will return a brand new `string` that is a copy of `romanNumeral` and has a lifespan of darn near zero. You can't read into it. Instead, return a reference so you don't get a copy, you get `romanNumeral`. `string& getRomanNumeral() `

Comment: @user4581301 Isn't that what the setter function was intended to do?

Comment: Darn good point. @πάνταῥεῖ .

Comment: Handy reading: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues). Of immediate interest is the notion of a prvalue, the most famous of which are variables returned by value and the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't my variable in my class work?

It works just fine, except that you're not returning it. When you are returning something ***by value***, you are essentially making a temporary copy of the variable. Of course, you can return it by reference:

```
string &getRomanNumeral() {
    return romanNumeral;
}
```

However, that doesn't really make much sense, since you no longer need `setRomanNumberal()`, you can simply use `getRomanNumberal()`:

```
romanObject.getRomanNumeral()="hello world";
```

The detail that you missed that setting the value of your class member is a part of initializing it by reading its value from `std::cin`. After you read the string, what do you need to do? You need to set it, so why do you want to use something called `getRomanNumeral()`? That doesn't make much sense, doesn't that?

So, really, your original approach was the correct one, something along the lines of:

```
string s;

cin >> s;

romanObject.setRomanNumeral(s);
```

You're getting the variable, from `cin`, and you're setting it in your object; you're not getting the existing value of this variable in your object, at any point.